# How to send whatsapp messages with selenium in an existing WhatsappWeb connection

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to send messages to whatsapp with Selenium and C#.

The problem is that, if as an example I am connected to Whatsapp in the current Chrome profile, when the WebDriver is initialized it open a new chrome, without profile and with whatsapp scan QR code.

I want to send messages using the existing browser connection.

I have tried:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalChromeOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
```

And also:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data");               
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalChromeOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
```

What I want: to open a new chrome instance, with the existing whatsapp connection,

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the correct profile.

This is the answer provided from [uzumaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3622232/uzumaki) on how to achieve that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\path\to\chrome\user\data") #e.g. C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=YourProfileDir') #e.g. Profile 3
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in")
```